# CRM Plugin will not update or do anything to change a fields value

Tags: c#, linq, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

So I have written a plugin to do some simple calculations and and update fields based upon certain conditions. The plugin compiles and doesn't cause any errors while profiling or create any instances where I can debug my code which is frustrating. Anyways without further ado here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BPT.PluginCommon.BaseClasses;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Xrm;

namespace Engage.Crm.Plugins
{
    public class VoidPayment : BPTPluginBase
    {
        bpt_DuesHeader oDuesHeader = new bpt_DuesHeader();
        Account org = new Account();
        public override void HandleAfterOp()
        {
            try
            {
                base.HandleAfterOp();
                var crmContext = new XrmServiceContext(this.OrganizationService);
                if (this.PluginExecutionContext.MessageName == MessageName.Create ||
                    this.PluginExecutionContext.MessageName == MessageName.Update)
                {
                    if (this.InputTargetEntity.Attributes.Contains("gih_void"))
                    {
                        var Void = (bool) this.InputTargetEntity.Attributes["gih_void"];
                        var voidReason = (OptionSetValue) this.InputTargetEntity.Attributes["gih_voidreason"];
                        var totalPayments = (Money) this.InputTargetEntity.Attributes["bpt_TotalPayments"];
                        var amountBilled =
                            crmContext.bpt_DuesHeaderSet.Where(
                                    o => o.bpt_DuesHeaderId == this.PluginExecutionContext.PrimaryEntityId)
                                .ToList()
                                .Sum(o => o.bpt_TotalAmountBilled == null ? 0 : o.bpt_TotalAmountBilled.Value);
                        if (Void)
                        {
                            this.oDuesHeader.bpt_TotalAdjustments = new Money(amountBilled);
                            this.oDuesHeader.bpt_TotalAmountBilled =
                                new Money(oDuesHeader.bpt_TotalAdjustments.Value + totalPayments.Value);
                            this.oDuesHeader.bpt_Balance = new Money(amountBilled);
                            if (voidReason.Value == 914020000)
                                //should be dropped not default option       
                            {
                                oDuesHeader.gih_terminationdate = DateTime.Now;
                            }
                        }
                        OrganizationService.Update(oDuesHeader);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.TracingService.Trace(this.ToString() + " {0}", "Exception: {0}", ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Sorry code is not formating well! Help! The plugin is registered as post-operation and synchronous. Any insight would be helpful and if a moderator could help format the code that would be greatly appreciated because it is not letting me add four spaces in certain places.

Comment: You need to set the Id on oDuesHeader for the update to work.

Comment: Ah so at the beginning when Im grabbing the attributes I should include bpt_duesheaderid =new Guide()?

Comment: you include the id, but not with new guid. you take the guid of the entity you want to update. something along the lines of this.oDuesHeader.Id=whateverentityyouwanttoupdate.id;

Comment: Okay thank you. I will try today. I knew it had to be something simple

Answer (score 0):

Plugins in CRM are created once, and then used multiple time, maybe even simultaneously, so besides setting the Id, don't use class level fields.  You're creating a race condition that could really do some unwanted changes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by class level fields?

Comment: bpt_DuesHeader oDuesHeader = new bpt_DuesHeader();
 Account org = new Account();

Comment: Oh okay right so instead just use var oDuesHeader = new bpt_DuesHeader()

Comment: Inside your HandleAfterOp method, yes.